# What are my firmware options for Desire HD

Tags: htc-desire-hd, device-firmware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

My requirements:

- Wifi hotspot needs to work properly since it often provides Internet access for my tablet.
- I connect to several Blutetooth devices they should work too. (Speaker, Car, send files to other phones)
- If possible i'd like the most recent Android version, as vanilla as possible.
- I want an easy, scheduled backup solution

I really don't need the whole HTC Sense thingie.

I am prepared to lose all data stored on my phone.

I am a bit of a newbie concerning custom roms, so maybe there is a proper tutorial on how to proceed with getting root, etc.

My Phone is currently on Android 2.3.5 Sense 3.0, Build Version 3.12.405.1 CL199157 release-keys (latest stock firmware i guess) and i do not have root.

Comment: [XDA's forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=765) has ICS/JB, [Cyanogenmod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/devices/htc-inspire) has officially only Gingerbread builds. The latter link has some info on how to upgrade/install aftermarket firmware ([or see here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/index.php?title=HTC_Desire_HD)). To have the latest/most vanilla fw: Search for AOSP builds (then CyanogenMod or AOKP, they add little clutter and preserve the vanilla feeling). I'd go for the most viewed thread with the most recent build on XDA (so it's hopefully well tested with fewer bugs).

Comment: Ah, one more noteworthy thing: JB-4.2 threw out bluez bt stack in favor of a new broadcom stack. Stick to 4.1 better (even the official 4.2 builds have some reported bt issues). I'd go for maybe [this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1778202), the rooting howto's [here](http://tau.shadowchild.nl/attn1/?cat=6)

Comment: Also take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/16575)